# Setup Magento 2.4.1 project on Github

Tags: magento2.4.1, github

I have created the Magento 2.4.1 project in my local system.

Now I have to set up this project on Github. I have created an account on Github.

Can someone tell me the steps to set up this on Github? Which files and directories should be upload on Github? What should be in the gitignore file?

Comment: hi there, did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-push-an-existing-project-to-github) for a quick ramp-up for managing your project with git and github.

As for the .gitignore file, [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-gitignore.html) the Magento official reference file. However, I find this relevant when you keep your whole project there, as in the whole magento installation files, not only your customizations. If this is what you need, then use it like this.

If you only work on an individual module that you need versioned (and not keep the whole Magento project on the repo), then I would consider adding only the module to the github repo. Afterwards, you could install it by composer, [here](https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/magento-2/create-magento-2-composer-module/) is an example. If you use this approach, you will need a simpler .gitignore, so I would delete the lines containing Magento installation specific folders (like app, lib, pub, media, var, etc).